# Get OAuth 2 Authorization token from DocuSign via Power Automate

Tags: oauth-2.0, docusignapi, power-automate

I am trying to use Power Automate to  setup OAuth connection with DocuSign. I do not want to use the custom connector. I am currently in the demo environment. How can I setup the redirect URI to redirect to a Power Automate HTTP triggered flow? Adding the HTTP flow URL as a redirect URI does not seem to work.

This seems really simple but I cannot get it to work and find minimal documentation. Has anyone done something similar? Any help appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried creating 2 flows, one for the authorization process, and the other for the redirect uri. At this point I was hoping to see a simple example to follow after 40+ hours of working on this. It seems I am missing something simple.

Comment: This is what I get when I try to trigger the Authorization flow with the Redirect URI being another HTTP trigger Flow. That URL is also added to the DocuSign App Redirect URI's.

Comment: {
    "statusCode": 302,
    "headers": {
        "X-DocuSign-TraceToken": "710dd714-8086-480d-bd39-8f33fdfd9739",
        "X-DocuSign-Node": "SE101DFE19",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload",
        "Referrer-Policy": "no-referrer,strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
        "Location": "/error",
    },
    "body": "<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>\r\n<h2>Object moved to <a href=\"/error\">here</a>.</h2>\r\n</body></html>\r\n"
}

Comment: Did you follow this - https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/get-the-flow-sending-docusign-envelopes-microsoft-power-automate ?

Comment: If you are not having luck with Auth Code Grant, you may want to try JWT maybe?

Comment: I did try following that document but it looks like a Power Automate HTTP triggered flow cannot be used as a redirect URI so I am looking for options that I can use maybe in Azure.

Comment: Did you try JWT? I'm not clear

Answer (score 0):

If your question is-Is there a way to set up the redirect URI to redirect to a Power Automate HTTP triggered flow without using a custom connector?

Answer- It is not possible to set up the auth code grant redirect uri to redirect to a power automate flow directly. it can only redirect to an https url.

thanks
sai

Comment: Okay if that is the case it makes sense. That is my exact question. I wonder what are my options using the M365 platform (Azure Function)? It's not really clear from the documentation.